# Can I write a C function compatible with a C++ function with reference parameter?

Tags: c++, c

I'm adding C wrapper for a C++ library. In some cases, a user defined callback function should be passed to the library. And the prototype of callback function have reference parameters. For example:

```
typedef void (*callBackFunc)(A& a, B& b);  //A, B are classes
```

I want to used below C prototype in external header file and some helper functions built-in the wrapper library to interprete object a and b.

```
typedef void (*callBackFunc)(void *a, void *b);
```

Helper functions in wrapper library:

```
extern "C" int getValueFromA(void *a) {
    A* pa = (A *)a;
    return pa->value;
}
....
```

Is this methods going to work? I'm not sure how reference parameter is implemented.

Comment: How can C wrapper function accept references to classes which are not part of C?

Comment: It is much simpler to call C code from C++ code than the reverse.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions

Answer (score 3):

Calling C from C++ works with some pain; trying to call C++ from C is *way* to much pain for non-masochists. It depends on the compiler(s), runtime versions, and a lot of other details. You will have to make sure your C program sets up the C++ environment, constructs any global objects used, ... When you finally get it working, the next compiler will roll along and break all your reverse engineering effort there.

Besides, "C functions taking references" just don't exist at all. *That* would need entertaining scaffolding... on *both* sides of the fence.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a reference is just part of the problem. If A & B are POD classes, then you may be able to make this work with a forwarding C++ wrapper, but it may not be standard compliant. And may break in future compiler versions etc or a different compiler. If A & B contain methods and if the callback needs to call these methods, it will be even more difficult.